# Grails controller class error

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, web, web-applications

I'm making an API call to a function in this controller class:

```
class CountryInfoController extends RestfulController {
static responseformats = ['json']

CountryInfoController(){
    super(CountryInfo)
}

def index(){}

def getCountryName(){
    System.out.println('all good')
}
```

}

However, it's giving me an error 500: Internal Server Error. [image]

I'm not sure if I'm missing a view or something - I'm new to Grails so I'm pretty confused about what's going on. Any thoughts would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller want's to render something.
If you aren't specify return data, using:
**return**, **respond** or **render**,
grails will try to find view in view folder with same name as method have.
Grails docs : http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#controllers

Answer (score 1):

Like Evgeny mentioned, the controller is trying to redirect to a view that doesn't exist. I'm assuming you will want to respond with JSON - and if so, you could **respond** with a domain object.

```
def getCountryName(){
    def c_info = CountryInfo.find(params.name)
    if(c_info != null)
        respond c_info
    // Otherwise, return error status
    response.status = 404
}
```